# arrivalTime in Optaplanner XML Solution file

Tags: optaplanner

We're having a difficult issue with Optaplanner.
We're working on a project for which we need to calculate an optimised vehicle route that takes into account specific hours between which the clients would like to be serviced.

We've been able to create a vrp-file, like given in the examples folder of Optaplanner. The hours of the time slots are coded in seconds. It loads correctly in the GUI-app.

However, it seems the routing problem is not feasible. When we don't consider the time slots, we're getting a result. We've looked into the XML file and noticed that the ArrivalTime doesn't correspond to the due times. In fact, we would like to know how to interpret the XML, to find our error.

```
<VrpVehicle id="19">
  <id>1</id>
  <capacity>75</capacity>
  <depot class="VrpTimeWindowedDepot" reference="14"/>
  <nextCustomer class="VrpTimeWindowedCustomer" id="20">
    <id>4</id>
    <location class="VrpRoadLocation" reference="11"/>
    <demand>1</demand>
    <previousStandstill class="VrpVehicle" reference="19"/>
    <nextCustomer class="VrpTimeWindowedCustomer" id="21">
      <id>2</id>
      <location class="VrpRoadLocation" reference="7"/>
      <demand>1</demand>
      <previousStandstill class="VrpTimeWindowedCustomer" reference="20"/>
      <vehicle reference="19"/>
      <readyTime>39600</readyTime>
      <dueTime>43200</dueTime>
      <serviceDuration>60</serviceDuration>
      <arrivalTime>3300060</arrivalTime>
    </nextCustomer>
```

Is someone familiar with the output generated by Optaplanner?
How can we retrieve the suggested route and what does the ArrivalTime mean? At the moment, we consider 4-2 as the optimal route for vehicle 19. Is this correct?

Kind regards,
MB

Answer (score 0):

Your interpretation about the route is correct, despite that it is vehicle 1 that serves customers 4 -> 2 and that it is not necessarily optimal but the current route.

The arrivalTime in the examples is updated by ArrivalTimeUpdatingVariableListener, which uses the locations of customers to determine the distance. Those distances cannot be used out of the box for your use-case as their unit is not seconds and probably scaled by a factor of 1000.

You will need to have the distance in seconds or scale your seconds to 'the unit' used in the examples to correctly calculate the arrivalTime.